# how to install ccrypt on CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I'm trying to install ccrypt on centOS, but I'm getting the following error:

```
yum install ccrypt
No package ccrypt available.
```

I tried to download the rpm and install it manually but it will require to install dependencies one by one (not very efficient).

I also tried installing the latest EPEL as mentioned [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/ccrypt-1.10-7.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) still same error

What shall I do?

I'm new to `yum` and CentOS, coming from Debian based flavors.

Answer (score 3):

-- Scrap that on CentOS6, it's only available for v7.

`ccrypt` is available in [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) (an extended package repository), so you have to activate it first.

```
sudo yum install epel-release 
sudo yum update 
sudo yum install ccrypt
```

Comment: nope that still did not work; I already installed epel previously but I did exactly what you posted and it did not work

Comment: ccrypt seems to be only available in EPEL for CentOS 7, not CentOS 6.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: You are right, I missed the `centos6` tag.

Comment: @AK_: If you are new to CentOS, why do you start with such an old version?

Comment: any alternative for ccrypt on centos6?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
It seems that you cannot install ccrypt via packages. The only way to get it working was to:

- download precompiled tar.gz file from [here](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/download/ccrypt-1.10.linux-x86_64.tar.gz)
- `chown user:user *` all files to my current username
- I was then able to run ccrypt

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to add the epel-release in your repolist you should go to this address

http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/ and download the binary rpm and do this example commands

```
rpm -Uvh ccrypt-1.11-1.x86_64.rpm
```

done